# Super simple shortcode not working

Tags: functions, filters, shortcode

Have been looking at various tutorials and answers here and elsewhere and just can't get this to work. Just trying to display a simple output from a shortcode as below, but it is just outputting the actual shortcode tag to the page instead of the content from the shortcode

**Functions.php**

```
<?php 
function welcome_roundels_func(){
    return "testing";
}
add_shortcode( 'welcome_roundels', 'welcome_roundels_func' );
?>

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

**Usage**

```
[welcome_roundels]
```

Is there anything else I have to do to enable shortcodes, or should the above work?

**Edit**
I am also using the below code to output the content

```
$welcomePage = get_post( 5 ); 
echo $welcomePage -> post_content;
```

Comment: Works for me. What is the point of `add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');`?

Comment: @s_ha_dum - Looking at various websites, people suggested adding that to 'enable' the shortcodes - didn't work for me though!

Comment: @s_ha_dum - Just added my output code to my question if that helps?

Comment: You don't need to "enable" shortcodes. That is nonsense. They are built into the WordPress Core and have been for a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$welcomePage = get_post( 5 ); 
echo $welcomePage -> post_content;
```

Shortcodes are processed on display by [via a filter on `the_content` which is called by the function `the_content()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L388). You've bypassed that functionality and are `echo`ing the raw post data.

You need to output your code using a [proper Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) or [explicitly process the shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode).

```
echo do_shortcode($welcomePage -> post_content);
```

Comment: Did the trick, thanks! Good explanation as well :)